# CSS Wrapper / Clearfix Resolution

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

Been having issues trying to get my floated elements to extend with all of my content. I've done some research but I have become officially stumped/exhausted. I've attempted a few clearfix resolutions, standard, micro, and inline, essentially everything listed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170).

My theories:

1. Something wrong with my syntax, or I'm not placing the `<div>` in the correct place.
2. I'm handling the content, or posts, in a fashion that will not allow me to extend the wrapper.
3. I'm an extremely special window licker.

---

### My Code

***Stylesheet:***

```
/*------------------------Wrapper------------------------*/

html, body, #wrapper, .bar, .line, .content{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}


#wrapper{
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}


.bar{
float: left;
width: 5%;
}

.line{
float: left;
width: 1%;
}

.content{
float:left;
width:88%;
}

.white{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red{
background-color: #A80000;
}

.black{
background-color: #000000;
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/bcq2U.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom right;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

/*------------------------Navigation------------------------*/

#nav{
width: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: #A80000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C4A23E;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; 
font-family: "Arial";
}

li{
float: left;
}

li a{
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
background-color:#A80000;
border-right: 1px solid #C4A23E; }

li a:hover{
color: #A80000;
background-color: #C4A23E; 
}

/*------------------------Text------------------------*/

h1 {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Arial";
text-alighn:center;
}

/*------------------------Boxes------------------------*/

.post{
float:left;
display:inline;
border-style:groove;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#A80000;
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/kOFxo.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
background-color:white;
width:60%;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:left;
padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin:1cm 0cm 1cm 1cm;
}

.logbox{
float:left;
border-style:groove;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#A80000;
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/kOFxo.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top left;
background-color:white;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
padding:80px 80px 80px 80px;
margin:1cm 0cm 1cm 1cm;
}

/*------------------------ClearfixA------------------------*/
/*
.clearfix:after{
content:".";
display:block;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
line-height:0;
height:0;
}

.clearfix{
display:inline-block;
}

html[xmlns].clearfix{
display:block;
}

*html.clearfix{
height:1%;
}
*/
/*------------------------ClearfixB------------------------*/

.cf:before,
.cf:after{
content:"";
display:table;
}

.cf:after{
clear:both;
}

.cf{
zoom: 1;
}
```

***Webpage:***

```
<? include "config.php";
include_once "markdown.php";
$my_html = Markdown($my_text);
?>

<!-- HTML Start -->

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleB.css"/>
<title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Wrapper  Start -->

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="wrapper cf">
<span class="bar white"></span>
<span class="line red"></span>
<span class="content black">

<!-- Content  Start -->

<h1>Project Hollywood</h1>

<div id="nav">

<?session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){?>

<ul>
<li><a href="login.php">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
</ul>

<?}
else{
?>

<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php">Admin Panel</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>

<?}
?>

</div>

<!-- Entries  Start -->

<?$query= "SELECT *
FROM entries
ORDER BY submitted DESC";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
?>

<?$i=0;
while ($i < $num){
$submit = mysql_result($result, $i, "submitted");
$title  = mysql_result($result, $i, "title");
$content = mysql_result($result, $i, "content");
$userid = mysql_result($result, $i, "userid");
$id = mysql_result($result, $i, "id");
?>

<?$q = "SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE $userid = uid";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$username = mysql_result($r, 0, "username");
?>

<span class="post">
<h3><?=$title?></h3>
<?=$submit?><br/>
<?=$username?>
<p><?=$content?></p><br/>

<?$que = "SELECT  t.tag
FROM tags AS t
INNER JOIN idx AS i ON t.tagid = i.tid
INNER JOIN entries AS e ON i.eid = e.id
WHERE e.id = '$id'";
$res = mysql_query($que);
$n = mysql_numrows($res);
$x=0;
?>

Tags:

<?while ($x < $n){
$tag = mysql_result ($res, $x, "tag");
$tid = mysql_result ($res, $x, "tid");
?>

<a href = "tag.php?tid=<?=$tag?>">
<?=$tag?></a>,

<?$x++;
}
?>

</span>

<?$i++;
}
?>

<!-- Entries & Content End -->

</span>
<span class="line red"></span>
<span class="bar white"></span>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper End -->

</body>
</html>

<!-- HTML End -->
```

---

Here is an image of what I am seeing on Chrome:

[image]

Any solutions, ideas, resources, help, advice would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I've read that FLOAT templates will be obsolete at some point in time and/or aren't the best way to design a webpage. Any suggestions or resources on how to do it otherwise would also be a welcomed response.

---

**EDIT** 4/24/13

Adding the code I receive after viewing the page source.

```
<!-- HTML Start -->

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleB.css"/>
<title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Wrapper  Start -->

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="wrapper cf">
<span class="bar white"></span>
<span class="line red"></span>
<span class="content black">

<!-- Content  Start -->

<h1>Project Hollywood</h1>

<div id="nav">


<ul>
<li><a href="login.php">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
</ul>


</div>

<!-- Entries  Start -->




<div class="post">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum Contd</h3>
2013-04-22 16:01:31<br/>
admin<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pharetra sapien metus, id imperdiet erat. Cras sit amet venenatis ante. Sed velit nunc, lobortis eget facilisis vitae, eleifend non magna. Praesent mattis justo a sapien tempor hendrerit. Vestibulum commodo cursus ipsum at feugiat. Morbi porta mauris at metus tempor elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum accumsan mauris ac mauris egestas dapibus. Curabitur ultrices purus vitae tellus ullamcorper posuere.</p><br/>


Tags:


<a href = "tag.php?tid=Lorem">
Lorem</a>,


<a href = "tag.php?tid=Ipsum">
Ipsum</a>,


<a href = "tag.php?tid=Lorem Ipsum">
Lorem Ipsum</a>,


</div>



<div class="post">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
2013-04-22 00:12:40<br/>
admin<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pharetra sapien metus, id imperdiet erat. Cras sit amet venenatis ante. Sed velit nunc, lobortis eget facilisis vitae, eleifend non magna. Praesent mattis justo a sapien tempor hendrerit. Vestibulum commodo cursus ipsum at feugiat. Morbi porta mauris at metus tempor elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum accumsan mauris ac mauris egestas dapibus. Curabitur ultrices purus vitae tellus ullamcorper posuere.</p><br/>


Tags:


<a href = "tag.php?tid=Lorem">
Lorem</a>,


<a href = "tag.php?tid=Ipsum">
Ipsum</a>,


</div>


<!-- Entries & Content End -->

</span>
<span class="line red"></span>
<span class="bar white"></span>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper End -->

</body>
</html>

<!-- HTML End -->
```

Also a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/afusob/1/edit) replication.

Comment: I think that sharing your outputted HTML, as opposed to your PHP, would be more helpful for us.

Comment: Have you tried using divs instead of spans for your posts?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue for us in a JSbin or something? It's hard to guess what the PHP might be doing!

Comment: @Barbs Yes, I have. I'll try again however just for humors sake but it was originally a <div> class

Comment: So we don't have access to your mysql db.. Unless you plan on giving us access to that, how about you open up your page in the browser, right click view source, and then give that instead of PHP that we can't use..

Comment: @ArleyM http://jsbin.com/afusob/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.content` within your css, add `overflow: auto;` . This will wrap your div around your content automatically.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` would be better. Auto causes scroll bars to appear, especially horizontal ones when an element can't fit within the dimensions of the parent container.

Comment: @Terry I used to be under the impression that `auto` would have added scroll bars, but it appears to do so only when the height has been specified or constrained somehow. If not (as in this case), then it will simply stretch. Also, `hidden` simply hides the subsequent posts, with no way to get at them..

Comment: Worked, but I had to had it under .line and .bar as well, but now I have ran into another issue, the scroll bar is on the inside of my wrapper. (Between .content and .line on the right side) Don't expect your assistance, you've been awesome thus far, wish I could up vote your answer.

Comment: @asifrc Anyway to move this scrollbar over to the far right?http://jsbin.com/afusob/1/edit

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like others on SO have tried with js. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889449/possible-to-move-scrollbar-position . Also, I think you should have upvote rights by now ;)