# How to change scroll bar position with CSS?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there any way to change position of scroll bar from left to right or from bottom to top with CSS ?

Comment: Scroll bar of your browser?

Comment: try this plugin
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
This jquery plugin will allow you to do custom css on scroll bar.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have a custom scrollbar and style that to position it how you like. The jscrollpane plugin suggested by @AwaisUmar is something I've used in the past and is a pretty good start.

Comment: Rather all browser, but if you know about specific browser, tell us

Comment: There's no way of doing it with pure CSS.

Comment: @Itay check out my answer. Pure CSS, All browsers that support rotation.

Comment: @avrahamcool I've already tried it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/QphS5/1/). But try and scroll with the mouse etc. the behavior becomes really strange.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Using CSS only:

Right/Left Flippiing: [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/uPwfn/1/)

```
.Container
{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.Content
{
    height: 300px;
}

.Flipped
{
    direction: rtl;
}
.Content
{
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Top/Bottom Flipping: [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/uPwfn/2/)

```
.Container
{
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.Content
{
    width: 300px;
}

.Flipped, .Flipped .Content
{
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: I don't see a top scrollbar on the flipped `div` in Chrome 29 on the *Top/Bottom Flipping* fiddle.

Comment: Apparently, its a [browser bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129186). I've Updated my Fiddle in the answer. check it now.

Comment: In Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 when I double rotate there are some problems with inputs/selection. In FF everything works OK.

Comment: @lechup can you post a fiddle? we'll try to help.

Comment: direction: rtl; doesn't move the scrollbar to left on Safari 8.0

Comment: I just discovered a bug (on Edge). If the flipped content contains a table with checkboxes on each of it's rows, the pointer-events are going to get messed up. If you select the last checkbox, it will select the first and vice-versa. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uPwfn/646/

Comment: problem: h-scroll is lost in firefox and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/milahu/2Lfqyx9s/2/ same problem with `transform: scale(-1, -1)`

Comment: @MilaNautikus what do you mean? working fine in chrome (even your fiddle)

Comment: i mean, there is no horizontal scrollbar, and i cant scroll horizontally using shift + scroll, in firefox 79 and chrome 83. probably a hardware issue (weak GPU). with only one transform, i see both scrollbars

Comment: Neat, but is it just me or does the content look a bit blurry when doing this?

Comment: Do you know anything about browser-support? Could this method be used in a production environment where a lot of browsers (IE11 included) have to be supported?

Does this somehow affect accessibility?
I think when following a trick down below where you change the direction `ltr` or `rtl`, this may affect accessibility, right?

Comment: so you flipped the content, then flip it again.  that is a neat trick

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way, by `rotating element` with the `scrollbar` for `180deg,` wrapping it's `content` into another element, and `rotating` that `wrapper` for `-180deg`.
Check the snippet below

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
}
#vertical {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: gold;
}
#vertical p {
  direction: ltr;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#horizontal {
  direction: rtl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: tomato;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#horizontal span {
  direction: ltr;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=vertical>
  <p>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content</p>
</div>
<div id=horizontal><span> content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever, but at least on my Linux firefox it has the side-effect of swapping the inset/outset effects of the handler and scrollbar; which is super-confusing.

Comment: look at this ansower
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889449/possible-to-move-scrollbar-position

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, fixed wit the `rtl` and `ltr` direction. So it will have native scroll efect, `scroll-down`  to bottom, and `scroll-up` to top

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed for the vertical, but not the horizontal.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out. Hope this helps

```
<div id="single" dir="rtl">
    <div class="common">Single</div>
</div>

<div id="both" dir="ltr">
    <div class="common">Both</div>
</div>



#single, #both{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}


.common{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: clever idea using `dir` learned something new, but i needed top and bottom too

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple way actually,
just change the "direction" property of the container element (the one that has the scroll bar) to "rtl" and the child element to "ltr"

```css
/*this is the container*/
#home {
    direction: rtl;/*this here*/
    padding-left: 20px;
}

/*this is the child*/
.content-container {
    direction: ltr;/*this here*/
    width: 100%;
}
```