# How to place the vertical scrollbar overflow to be placed at the element's left?

Tags: jquery, css, html

By default the overflow's vertical scrollbar is at the right of the element :

[image]

How to make it at the element's left ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css

Comment: it is not the same !

Comment: Hi, http://jsfiddle.net/jw3jsz08/1/ this may help you