# move scrollbar to top in datatable Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, position, scrollbar

I'm using Primefaces 5.1 It is possible to move scrollbar from bottom table to top? 
[image: picture]

Comment: Have you tried it with CSS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css

Comment: @Opfau: That does not work since it requires the html of the component to be modified. See the answer... I used the question you refer to, to get to my answer. Will explicitly add it there

Comment: You are right. I tried it with a `p:dataTable` and also the content is rotated (of course) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as far as I know. The scrollbar is a native scrollbar from the OS and cannot be moved to the top without modifying the html of the component. The latter is what is done in [How to change scroll bar position with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css) and why it will not work here