# How to auto scroll down to list while messages are coming

Tags: javascript, html

Hello Everybody I have a div which lists messages with `<ul>` here is the code ;

```
  <section class="portfolio-section masonry-style">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>TOPLU KONUŞMA</h2>
        <div class="container" style="max-height:500px;min-height:500px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;">
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
            <ul id="discussion"></ul>
        </div>
        </div>  

</section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="contact-form">
            <textarea name="comment" id="message" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
            <div class="submit-area">
                <input type="submit" id="sendmessage" value="Gönder">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

script ;

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var currentMember = '@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Name)';
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };

            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(currentMember);
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
```

so As you see it doesnt auto scroll down while messages are coming. this is real time chat. So how can I autoscroll down while messages are coming

Comment: Its unclear until you provide a demo.

Comment: uploaded a picture @BhojendraNepal

Comment: could you provide source of the message box from your browser and your javascript?

Comment: @Woody shared everything. I just need auto scroll when list updated. I use realtime chat

Comment: try to add the following line after your message append in javascript:
`$('ul#discussion').scrollTop($('ul#discussion')[0].scrollHeight);`

see if that works

Comment: it didnt work :( I put it where it says '  $('#message').val('').focus();' @Woody

Comment: How about put after this?
`$('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');`

Comment: its writing '[object HTMLTextAreaElement]' but still no auto scroll @Woody

Comment: or is there any way to make list descend ? @Woody

Comment: did you add a source ref to jquery? `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Woody yes I have higher library too

Comment: Try change the previous one to this. I might have choose the wrong container at first. `$('div.container').scrollTop($('div.container')[0].scrollHeight)`

Comment: @furkan, in stead of jquery, you may use css to fix the position of scroll bar

Comment: didnt work or half way worked. still cant go in the same time but at least it went half way down :( @Woody .

Comment: I'm not very good with css or jquery. do you have code example ? @Astro

Comment: Half way? That's weird. How about you put at where the first time you did:
`$('#message').val('').focus();`

Comment: I put it there. sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. kinda weird yes

Comment: @furkan using jquery, what woody suggests was best.. For css refer this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css]

Comment: Oh wait, I saw you have multiple div container class now. That's why the jquery can't select the div properly.
You should add in an ID for this line `<div class="container" style="max-height:500px;min-height:500px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;" id="messageContainer">`. Then change the code to be added to `$('div#messageContainer').scrollTop($('div#messageContainer')[0].scrollHeight)`.

Comment: @furkan, the format for changing the position using jquery is `$("#yourDiv").scrollTop($("#yourDiv").prop('scrollHeight'))`

Comment: @Woody works like a charm man thanks !! =)

Comment: @Astro thanks a lot the problem was div names as woody said

Comment: both format should works as it is just version difference. In case it doesn't works, just switch around the format.

Comment: @furkan I am glad it helps, let me put those into answer from for easier reference.

Comment: @furkan you are welcome!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add in id for the following line. Jquery can't select the correct `div` if you do not have an ID for that `div`, since you have multiple `div.container`.

`<div class="container" style="max-height:500px;min-height:500px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;" id="messageContainer">`

Then use jquery to scroll the `div` using through the following code:

`$('div#messageContainer').scrollTop($('div#messageContainer')[0].scrollHeight)`

Put the code

(1) Right after your new message is appended

`$('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');`

or

(2) After you clear your input box.

`$('#message').val('').focus();`