# Is it possible to change the scrollbar to the left of a listview?

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx, scrollbar

I have a ListView, I want to scroll and I want the ScrollBar to appear on the left side of the ListView instead of the right side. Is there a straightforward way to do that?

Comment: Can I ask why? Nobody will think to look there.

Comment: It's because my poor choice of design, I can't place it on the right because it'll look out of place.

Comment: Hmm, well regardless of my opinion, I'm still interested to see how it should be done. I'd recommend using a different design though if it means it will ultimately look better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in css you may try for the scrolling container: **[demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LNKagm)**

```
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
```

and then you need a reset for the children .

I tested this long ago and it did not work in every browsers, from update to updates, it change sometimes ... *... last safari for windows doesn't take it*.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-unicode-bidi
>
> https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#unicode-bidi

```css
ul {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
  border:solid;
}
li {
  text-align:left;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction:ltr;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item.</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgot to mention it was for JavaFX. Do you know how I'd be able to do it in JavaFX?

That is a great example for HTML-CSS though!

Comment: @Lewis no unfortunately, i figure out this after, i only reacted on the css tag , but you could probably do like a custom scrollbar , create a new one , bend the regular to the new and hide it (similar to create custom scollbar via js for regular html/css)

Comment: @Lewis  looks like there is an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134155/move-the-vertical-scroll-bar-of-a-scroll-panel-to-the-left-side