# Is there a way to invert the scrollbars position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to place the horizontal scrollbar on the top and the vertical scrollbar on the left? [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tof8sLbu/)

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
margin: 15px;
}

#vertical {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
background: gold;  
}

#horizontal {
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<div id=vertical>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content</div>
<div id=horizontal> content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content_content</div>
```

Comment: No, and this is a terrible idea.  Changing the user interface on any device where people are use to the position of re-usable controls to another position makes an absolute terrible user experience.

Comment: You could hide the scroll bar and create your own

Comment: Don't know if you still looking for it, but here I've created an example: http://jsbin.com/nudere/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: It works great! Unfortunately I did already accept the 'mark as duplicate' by the community and can't set your version as the right answer; but since you presented solution different of the duplicate one, I'm not going to delete this post. Thanks for your effort;

Comment: @itsgoingdown Your answer seemed useful to at least one person, so consider posting it on the duplicate (or another appropriate question).

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom thanks for the heads up. posted it on the original question

Comment: @freestock.tk itsgoingdown [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35787639/3614835) on the original question.  You can upvote it if you think it was helpful.