# Make the scroller of div at the left by default

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to change the scrollbar to the left by default, But
I don't want to make it with JavaScript because I'm already using it
in some other things on the same div like (the user have the ability
to scroll app without forcing him to go down when there is an update
....)

> My project is a chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially a duplicate of this q: [How to change scroll bar position with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css)

Using different combinations of direction:rtl and transform:rotateX(###deg) should help you toward your desired result.
See the answer from @avrahamcool in the q above

*Note: add more example text if your browser doesn't display scrollbars right away.

Comment: This could move the whole scrollBar But I'm talking about the Scroller, And thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: Hmm not sure then, sorry. Consider that for implementation in a chatroom, this could be confusing for the user, since the position of the scroller usually indicates where they are looking in relation to the page, i.e. if the scroller is at the bottom, they may think there isn't anything left to read.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAhhhh Got , I'm really sorry for that , really sorry, Thank you anyway :) +1