# Scroll Bar at Top and Bottom in DataTables

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am working on DataTables. I need scrollbar at the top and bottom of my table. I have more than 25 rows and my table overflow.

Every time I need to scroll down for horizontally scroll the table

Top of table:

[image: top of table]

Bottom of table:

[image: bottom]

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table

Comment: please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css

Comment: its not working for me @zan

Answer (score -1):

I solved this, by adding a max-height to the table, which is smaller than 100vh, so that there is a horizontal and a vertical scrollbar (Like in this  Demo, when all options are activated: http://fixedheadertable.com/ ). But please notice, that you have to destroy the plugins and initialize a new fixed header table after resize.

Comment: i am not using fixed header for this @Martin

Comment: yes, i see - but this can be your solution too. In any case, you have to edit the code. My example is only an example for how the result could look like :)

Comment: thnks bro @Martin P. but i got the solution from this link                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table