# Show Horizontal scrollbar under the header in Kendo grid

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with the Horizontal scrollbar. By default, the position of the scrollbar is at the bottom of the grid.

But my requirement is to show the horizontal scrollbar at top of the grid(Under Grid header).

Is it possible to do it? Please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this answer [How to change scroll bar position with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998575/4825632)
and modifying it to a scrollable kendo grid using style rule

```
.k-grid-content,
.k-grid-content table {
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

will put the horizontal scrollbar on top.

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/etIYa

If you are using virtual scrolling, then you will have to change the style rule to compensate as the structure of the grid is different between a scrollable and a virtual scrollable kendo grid.

Comment: Thanks Dread! It is working as expected. Is there any way to have a fixed horizontal scrollbar like we have fixed header (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/fixed-headers-grid). Any Suggestion?

Comment: That's different.  Instead of flipping the elements, you have to render your own scrollbar and update it. Here's and demo combining the example you linked with https://www.telerik.com/forums/top-horizontal-scrollbar-in-grid: https://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EhaXaK.  Any more and you will have to put me on the payroll ;)

Comment: Thanks for the Demo Dread! but we end up having the 2 horizontal scrollbar's right? So, I am flipping and showing only one scrollbar according to the header location. So, that users will see the scrollbar under the header only.

Comment: In my second demo, I removed the "flipping" CSS and only implementing the "manual" scrollbar (and .k-grid-content { overflow-x: hidden } to prevent the built-in scrollbar from showing)