# Fullcalendar : Way to have scroller on top of the scheduler?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

In full calendar the scroll bar is at the bottom.  I would like it to be at the top.  Is that possible?

This is with the full calendar scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're talking about your browser scrollbars.

This answer should help you change their position with some css.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998575/6998283

I don't think it's possible to change their position within fullcalendar without some custom code.

Hope it helps.