# How to Get a Scroll Bar to be Ontop of Content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have an HTML element with some drop down boxes inside. The element is very narrow so when all of the boxes are extended they go off the bottom and a scroll bar appears on the right. As the element is very narrow there is now much room for the content and the scroll bar pushes everything to the side make it even smaller.

I want the scroll bar to:

1. Appear only when the mouse is hovering over the body
2. Be on top of the content rather than push it to the side

Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Make a div smaller than conent, and the overflow to be displayed on hover.

[This answer could give you a better insight.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997724/how-to-change-scroll-bar-position-with-css)

```css
.Container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

.Container:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;

}

.Content {
  width: 300px;
}

.Flipped,
.Flipped .Content {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<h1>Show the scroll bar on hover</h1>
<div class="Container Flipped">
    <div class="Content">I'm in Content and I'm very long</div>
</div>
```

Comment: All that does is move the contents out of frame and add a horizontal scroll bar. I want everything to remain where it is, just with the vertical side bar hovering over it.