# Move the scrollbar from the bottom to the top

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll, scrollbar

Is there a way to move the scrollbar from bottom to the top of the div? I tried to put any margins to the `-webkit-scrollbar` and `-webkit-scrollbar-track` but without any result ?!

```
<div class="accordion__content">
    <ul class="list" #timelineList>
      <li
        class="list__item"
        *ngFor="let ecp of incidentAnalysis?.incidentTimeline.ecps; index as i"
        [style.width.px]="getIncidentListWidthDependingOnEventLength()"
      >

        <app-event-timeline
          class="fg-chart"
          [alarmData]="prepareIncidentTimelineChartData(ecp.alarms)"
          [startDate]="convertToDate(incidentAnalysis?.startTime)"
          [endDate]="convertToDate(incidentAnalysis?.endTime)"
          [timelineVisibleWidth]="incidentTimelineVisibleWidth"
          [timelineLeftContentWidth]="incidentTimelineLeftContentWidth"
          [minuteToPixel]="incidentTimelineMinuteToPixel"
          [timelineWidth]="getIncidentTimelineWidthDependingOnEventLength()"
        ></app-event-timeline>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The scrollbar is on the ul.
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998575 might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg)`

example :

```css
.Container
{
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.Content
{
    width: 400px;
    transform:rotateX(180deg); // in order to rotate the text back to 0
}

.rotateX
{
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Top scrollbar</h1>
<div class="Container rotateX">
    <div class="Content">text text text text text text text.....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this now, but without any changes

Comment: could you provide your code for me to take a look

Comment: I have updated the question with my code.